# How can I search/print column names from my metadata in an AWS Glue python environment?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have setup Python to do ETL programming using an AWS Glue dev endpoint.

I was hoping to create a function that could find all other tables which have the same variable name in that table - i.e. a function that lists that the table names automatically and the columns within them.

Basically was hoping to do what you could using columns with dataframes in pandas. e.g: just like i can do the following in pandas

```
columns = df.columns
```

I was hoping to do something equivalent to:

```
dbs = awsGlue.databases
tables_db1 = dbs[0].tables
```